# JIRA Custom Field Context issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I created a custom field(select list) called 'Type', and in Project A, I have 3 issue types, is there a way to configure 'Type' with different select list options for each issue type under Project A? Thanks

for example:

- Issue Type 1, 'Type' with values 1, 2, 3
- Issue Type 2, 'Type' with values A, B, C
- Issue Type 3, 'Type' with values X, Y, Z

Comment: Yes, create a different Context for each issue type in the custom field Configuration screen.

Comment: YES, the problem is, if I set context for project A and issue type A combo, the next time I want to set context for project A and issue type B combo, project A won't be shown in the list.

Comment: @Kuf: Deleting your comment the first time around was enough. No need to repost it.

Comment: @BoldClock didn't know it will hurt/annoying anyone. Hoped that maybe if i'll write it again that maybe the user will check the answer, ask if he need more help of accept the answer otherwise. I think it's for the best both for me and for other users, I'll have another accepted answer, and everyone else will know if my answer could help them. It cases like this, I shouldn't do anything? just to know for the future...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can create dynamic fields using Javascript, have a look at [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732143/how-to-add-country-selection-field-to-jira#answer-12732144).

This way you could fill the select options with a pre-defined list according or purely dynamic one. If you need help with the coding part feel free to ask..